# java modular division sanity check

Tags: java, division, modular

If my modular division is right; `1 / 5 mod 11 = 9`.  Can someone confirm this?

However, in Java; `1 / 5 % 11 = 0;`

I'm not sure what's going on here, is it my syntax, do I need to bracket it in someway?

I'm getting confused now :)

Can someone advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the same as (1/5) mod 11.

(or alternatively the same as 1 / (5 mod 11) which is still 1/5 == 0 [from left to right it would actually be (1/5) mod 11 though])

1 / 5 = 0 (for integers)

0 mod 11 = 0

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it's happening.  I shall have to do some more research. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> 1 / 5 mod 11 = 9. Can someone confirm this?

(9 * 5) % 11 = 45 % 11 = 1. So, yes 9 is the modular multiplicative inverse of 5 in the land of 'mod 11'.

The problem is: Java only has integers and no modular arithmetic. In Java, `%` is just an operator like `*`.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

> The notion of modular arithmetic is *related* to that of the remainder in division.

So, `mod 11` and `% 11` are related but not the same thing!

Comment: You're correct.  I was approaching it in the wrong manner.  To get my answer, I've just implemented and tested this:

    for (int i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
                    if (i * y % mod == 1) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

http://www.difranco.net/cop2551/java_op-prec.htm indicates that *, / and % have the same precedence order, but that in an expression / will have precedence over %.  So your Java result above is correct w.r.t the JLS.

Comment: The link you cite doesn't support your answer in the slightest, and your answer embodies a contradiction in terms. Either they have the same precedence or one has precedence over the other. In fact, operators of equal precedence are evaluated left to right. None of which is sufficient to explain the OP's issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of operator precedence.

Java does passes where it simplifies the express.  It does some operations, then n the next pass it does some others.  The "highest" operators are done first.  For example multiplication is before addition.  The operators `( )` are in the first pass and let you override the normal order things are done.

See this chart: [enter link description here](http://www.cs.uwf.edu/~eelsheik/cop2253/resources/op_precedence.html)

`%` is in the same group as `*` and `/`.  They are done left to right.

So you want `(1/5) % 11`

But you have another problem in that this will be done in floating point math, so you will get an approximation not the exact correct answer.

You need to use the `BigInteger` class instead of the built in primitives.

Comment: "Java does passes where it simplifies the express. It does some operations, then n the next pass it does some others.". This is simply not the case. Java, like any other programming language, uses RPN and a stack to evaluate expressions. There are not multiple "passes". There is simply the order in which the operators occur in the RPN.

Comment: I under this and you are correct.  However, I was simplifying the answer for a beginner.

Comment: Simplifying the answer by making it more complicated than it really is?